# Do I need a support contract to test my web application on solaris 10

Tags: solaris, webserver, testing, licenses

I need to install Solaris 10 and I'm wondering if I need a support contract, on the download page it says that you need a support contract for production use, but I'm not too sure what production use mean, I want to test out a website I'm developing on that platform, does that count as production use? I really wouldn't consider it to be production use, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need a support contract.  When it is just you and other developers using the box for development work, then the purpose of the server is development.  If someday you decide to let customers start accessing the website on that machine, then it becomes production.  The litmus test I use is `(customers or revenue) == production`.  Testing, QA, QC, etc all fall under development and are not production.